# useState defaultValue from props caused extra rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component says Name, so Name has a prop call defaultValue, it looks like

```
const Name = ({defaultValue}) => {

const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(defaultValue)

return <div>something<div>
}
```

but it will rerender even though the prop remain the same

```
<Name defaultValue={{'key':1, 'value':'One'}} />
```

because `{'key':1, 'value':'One'}` === `{'key':1, 'value':'One'}` equal to false. What can I do in Name component to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the object `{'key':1, 'value':'One'}` to a const *outside* of the component (not in the render function):

```
const defaultValue = {'key':1, 'value':'One'}

const App = () => (  
  <Name defaultValue={defaultValue} />
)
```

Or use `useMemo` inside the component:

```
const defaultValue = useMemo(() => ({'key':1, 'value':'One'}), [])

<Name defaultValue={defaultValue} />
```

Wrapping `Name` with `React.memo()`:

```
const checkPropsWithoutDefault = ({ defaultValue, ...prevProps }, { defaultValue, ...nextProp } }) => {
   const keys = [new Set([...Object.keys(), ...Object.keys()])]
   return keys.every(key => prevProps[key] === nextProp[key])
};

const MemoizedName = React.memo(Name, checkPropsWithoutDefault);
```

Comment: it is possible to let the Name component to handle it? says Name is a hosted npm package, if it caused lag, no one would notice it. Since the Name designed the prop as object, it should be responsible for the optimization internally not externally.

Comment: You can wrap name with `React.memo()` and ignore the different value.

Comment: you mean `export default useMemo(Name)` ?

Comment: Yep, and you'll also need to add a test that excludes `defaultValue` from the check.

Comment: hmm so complicated, I haven't seen such approach to solve this issue.

Comment: The 1st approach is the simpler - if it doesn't actually change, stick it in a `const`.

Comment: can't put out side of the component, because the object is defaultState of a state in Name component.

Comment: You are passing it to Name somewhere

Comment: see this example https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-glitter-93hq7

render got log twice when the object value been passed in the ExternalComponent is the same.

Comment: Any of my suggestions would probably solve your issue. Please try them.